# How to get a server port from an express variable

Tags: node.js, express, port

I have an ExpressJS app that looks like this:

```
const http = require("http")
const express = require('express') //Version ^4.16.4
const app = express()
const server = http.createServer(app)
[...]
app.listen(3000)
```

And I'm developing a module that will be plugged into express like:

```
const myPlugin = require("myPlugin")
myPlugin.start(server, 3000)
```

But, for simplicity, I want the developer to only reference the server:

```
const myPlugin = require("myPlugin")
myPlugin.start(server)
```

And the module will automatically extract the port. In a prior express versions I used to read,

```
var port = server._connectionKey.split("::::")[1]
```

But in newer versions of ExpressJS this variable is buried deep in the server and it no longer contains the port number (i.e. for an app running on 3000 I'm getting *"6::::0"*, while on a previous version I would get *"6::::3000"*)

**Where can I find the port number information in the latest Express version?** 
**Which is the most reliable way to get this number?**

Comment: Did you try : 
var port = server.address().port

Comment: You could also just add your own port property to the server object and let the plugin get it from that property.  `server._port = 3000` and then the plug-in can access `server._port`.